# C language problem with this confusing typedef

Tags: c

how do i understand something like this

`typedef void string(char * str,int num); 
string * stringptr;`

is `stringptr` a function pointer that point to a funtion like `string`

Comment: Ask yourself what the type of `string` would be if the keyword `typedef` were erased.  Once you are sure of that;  then the meaning of adding `typedef` is that `string` names that type you just answered.

Comment: so stringptr is a function pointer,right?

Comment: Not directly relevant, but `string` is a really bad name for that type.

Comment: @Arthur Yes that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typedef defines a function type. It is not terribly useful in itself, but it allows us to declare a function pointer to that type, just as we declare a normal object pointer. And that's what `string * stringptr;` does - declaring a function pointer to a function of the form `void string(char * str,int num);`

Comment: You can also use a `typedef`ed function type in a function declaration (but not in a function definition).

Comment: @KeithThompson I wouldn't really recommend that though, as it can look a bit confusing.

Comment: Agreed. [more because comments can't be too short]